# How can I access my ViewModel from the View and associated code behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, viewmodel

I am a real beginner at ASP.NET and working with MVC2 + EF4 in Visual Studio 2010.

I am trying to use the MVVM pattern and strongly typing my View to a ViewModel.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"        AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="~/Views/Options/Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OptionsViewModel>" %>
```

My OptionsViewModel looks like this:

```
 public class OptionsViewModel
{
    public List<DeskPreference> DeskPreferences { get; set; }
    public List<DayPreference> DayPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I create a new OptionsViewModel and do return View(myOptionsViewModel);

Then, for example, I want to check/uncheck some boxes based on what is in DayPreference. I don't get how to access the model from my code behind file, which looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DeskRota_v1.ViewModels;

public class OptionsPage : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OptionsViewModel>
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        setCheckBoxes();
    }

    private void setCheckBoxes()
    {           
        foreach (DayPreference dayPreference in Model.DayPreferences)
        {
\\ check boxes here
}
}
```

It comes up with "The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context". Also if I try to do <% Model. %> in the view there is no intellisense, which I thought there should be. Could somebody please explain what I am doing wrong? How am I supposed to access the ViewModel and its properties?

Comment: If you are using asp.net mvc there is no code behind file. The entire model is different.

Comment: You seem to be missing some key concepts. Rather than work with what you have, I would recommend spending a couple hours looking over the basics, and then revisit your specific problem. Also I would recommend using MVC 3 or 4 instead, as the syntax is cleaner in my opinion. Here's an intro from Microsoft, to get you started on the basics:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: In addition to the above advice, I should add that you don't need the MVVM since the framework is built around the MVC pattern. You can still have a view model in MVC.

Comment: @Chad I had read this post which prompted me to try to use codebehind in an effort to not end up with 'messy' views. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355106/asp-net-mvc-views-can-i-use-code-behind) I was under the impression that I had the choice to use a code behind file if I wanted, is that not correct?

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the comments and link - I had seen this article before and skimmed through. I will go back and follow it in more detail. If there's any chance you can give me some pointers on what I am missing that would be appreciated! I wanted to use at least MVC 3 for this project but unfortunately that is not possible...

Comment: That may have worked in MVC preview 5, but we are WAY beyond that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller will have two overloads of each action method for each view that you need to post back: one with an HttpGet signature and one with an HttpPost signature. The GET version will be called on the first load of the page and will set the initial page values.

The POST version will be called on form submit and accept your viewmodel as an arg. MVC will automagically reconstruct it with the values that were posted in your form (assuming you're using relatively simple types. More complex types is doable but more complicated).

My own convention is to have a work unit in the ViewModel that is responsible for persisting or otherwise processing the values that were submitted. Do NOT put this sort of thing in the controller.

Your viewmodel will need a parameterless constructor, which is the version MVC will use when reconstituting it on page submit. In general I also have a second constructor I use on the GET version so that the VM can instantiate it's initial values.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int somethingICareAbout)
{
  return View(new IndexViewModel(somethingICareAbout));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
{
  viewModel.SaveChanges()/DoWork()/Whatever();
  return View(new viewModel());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would accept but I am still confused as to how to access the properties in my ViewModel. I did have a couple of constructors for my ViewModel, for example in my controller I have `OptionsViewModel optionsViewModel = new OptionsViewModel(deskOptions, dayOptions);
            return View(optionsViewModel);` Is this along the right lines? How do I then do something like `Model.DayPreferences` in the view?

Comment: Correct. Pass the instantiated view model when you return the view as you did above. In your view, you need to declare the model your view is using (@model OptionsViewModel) and then anyplace you want to consume one of the values or methods from your model simply put it into your view: (Your Desk Options: <span>@Model.DeskOptions</span>). Think of your view model as a kind of view helper that contains all of the information and methods that view needs to do its job thoughout the entire lifecycle of the view, from initial load & paint, to form submission, to reload, etc.

Comment: This answer and your comments definitely put me on the right lines. I think I have more of a handle on what I'm doing now. I think the immediate problem was that I was trying to inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OptionsViewModel>... when I changed to Inherits="mynamespace.Views.OptionsPage" it could find the model again without declaring it anyplace else in the view? Anyway thanks for the help.